# Why IPWhois in Python 2.7 can't get anwer?

Tags: linux, python-2.7

I have installed python 2.7, IPWhois etc.
I can get anwer to IP address: 74.125.225.229.
But I can't get anwer for IP: 1.209.148.1.
Can anyone help?

```
Python 2.7.9 (default)
[GCC 4.9.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
from ipwhois import IPWhois
ip = '74.125.225.229'
obj = IPWhois( str(ip) )
res=obj.lookup_whois()
print(res)
{'raw': None, 'asn_registry': 'arin', 'asn_country_code': 'US', 'asn_date': '2007-03-13', 'asn_cidr': '74.125.225.0/24', 'raw_referral': None, 'nir': None, 'query': '74.125.225.229', 'referral': None, 'nets': [{'updated': '2012-02-24', 'handle': 'NET-74-125-0-0-1', 'description': 'Google Inc.', 'postal_code': '94043', 'address': '1600 Amphitheatre Parkway', 'cidr': '74.125.0.0/16', 'emails': ['network-abuse@google.com', 'arin-contact@google.com'], 'city': 'Mountain View', 'name': 'GOOGLE', 'created': '2007-03-13', 'country': 'US', 'state': 'CA', 'range': '74.125.0.0 - 74.125.255.255'}], 'asn': '15169'}
ip = '1.209.148.1'
obj = IPWhois( str(ip) )
res=obj.lookup_whois()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/.../src/ipwhois/ipwhois/ipwhois.py", line 184, in lookup_whois
field_list=nir_field_list, is_offline=False
  File "/.../src/ipwhois/ipwhois/nir.py", line 497, in lookup
form_data=form_data
  File "/.../src/ipwhois/ipwhois/net.py", line 977, in get_http_raw
request_type=request_type, form_data=form_data
  File "/.../src/ipwhois/ipwhois/net.py", line 931, in get_http_raw
form_data = urlencode(form_data)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 1324, in urlencode
raise TypeError
TypeError: not a valid non-string sequence or mapping object
```

Comment: Can you open http://whois.kisa.or.kr/eng/whois.jsc and see "400 Bad Request"? It looks like a network issue.

Comment: Yes, I can open this site. This is not problem with access to network. I think it's something in IPWhois module to python 2.7. 
https://github.com/secynic/ipwhois

Comment: If it was network issue I can't get anwer for first IP address... 74.125.225.229.

Comment: The exception was raised when the URL got retried (line 977 of `net.py` is in `except` block) so there are some issue within the `ipwhois`' code. You can specify `retry_count=0` to `lookup_whois()` to see what the original error is. I can not reproduce your problem on my mac.

Comment: res=obj.lookup_whois( retry_count=0)
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/.../src/ipwhois/ipwhois/ipwhois.py", line 184, in lookup_whois
        field_list=nir_field_list, is_offline=False
      File "/.../src/ipwhois/ipwhois/nir.py", line 497, in lookup
    form_data=form_data
      File "/.../src/ipwhois/ipwhois/net.py", line 983, in get_http_raw
    url))
    ipwhois.exceptions.HTTPLookupError: HTTP lookup failed for http://whois.kisa.or.kr/eng/whois.jsc.

Comment: Well you saw the error. It's a network issue since your DNS server can't find that domain.

Comment: No, it isn't :) My DNS can find this domain and ip address of this site is 203.255.210.120. This script which is used in module "whois.jsc" doesn't exist on this site. When I try open it I get "400 Bad Request". Please check https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html 10.4.1 400 Bad Request. btw can you open this link http://whois.kisa.or.kr/eng/whois.jsc ?

Comment: Solve it. It's problem with iptables/firewall. Thx for help.

Answer (score 1):

[From the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41160414/why-ipwhois-in-python-2-7-cant-get-anwer/52834234#comment69558620_41160414) (edited):

> Solved it. It was a problem with iptables/firewall. Thanks for the help.

- th3V